# Gitconfig file has disappeared but is still there

Tags: git, git-config

I needed to make some edits to my gitconfig file located in my `home` directory under Linux.
I have a drive mapped from Windows to this location so for ease I just opened the file in Notepad to check the contents.

I now have the following problem:

1. Where my gitconfig file should be the filename is blank
2. There is an icon, but it's simply a Notepad icon
3. File description under Windows still says gitconfig

How on earth did I obliterate the name and how do I get it back?
I've tried deleting the file and recreating from Linux, but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the file is not `gitconfig`, but `.gitconfig`. This means on Linux it is a hidden file. On Windows though it is a file without name and with extension `gitconfig`. So what you see is absolutely correct and you have no problem.

Comment: Previously it was showing as .gitconfig in the filename in windows. Can I be certain that it assigning Notepad as the default application in windows won't have altered the file?

Comment: Be sure to check the line endings if you opened it in notepad (not notepad++)

Comment: In Windows you have a setting that (in my opinion very bad choice) is on by default with is "don't show extensions of known file types". This makes it possible to have file called `funny.pdf.exe` with an embedded PDF icon that will seem to the common user like a PDF that he might open and instantly he has a virus installed. This setting is one of the first things I switch off if I'm forced to use a Windows system. In your case, before assigning Notepad the extension was not known and thus shown. Now it is a known extension and thus not shown in the normal explorer view. So yes, you can be.

Comment: Have taken off that annoying setting. Can now see the file correctly.